# Word Open XML Mail Merge

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I'm attempting to manually create a mail merge using Word's XML (from Word 2007).  I have the following XML which isn't working:

```
<w:mailMerge>
    <w:mainDocumentType w:val="catalog" />
    <w:linkToQuery />
    <w:dataType w:val="native" />
    <w:connectString w:val="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TheServer;Data Source=." />
    <w:query w:val="SELECT * FROM  `Table` WHERE `id_field` = 7" />
    <w:dataSource r:id="rId1" />
    <w:activeRecord w:val="0" />
</w:mailMerge>
```

I can't really figure out from the documentation what I'm supposed to do.  This is just a mail merge from a database table.  It says there's an error on the line `<w:mainDocumentType w:val="catalog" />`.  I've looked up possible values of `w:val` without any luck.  I can't find any decent documentation on it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[DII](http://www.documentinteropinitiative.com/implnotes/ECMA-376/sec_34_24_13_0_0_0.aspx) has all of the documentation and you can also look up on this site, like the `mainDocumentType` is listed as a [`CT_MailMergeDocType`](http://www.documentinteropinitiative.com/implnotes/ECMA-376/c3d484e1-be73-4c35-a720-d69cc23c7c6c.aspx). Upon searching for that, I get  which then tells me to look up [`ST_MailMergeDocType`](http://www.documentinteropinitiative.com/implnotes/ECMA-376/dfb1376d-9b91-40a3-bed0-efdf6ef9f6df.aspx), where it lists the types.

Also, OpenXML Developer has some basic intro articles to MailMerge with WordprocessingML:

- [Mail merge in WordProcessingML using
  System.IO.Packaging API](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/2542.aspx)
- [Mail Merge in WordProcessingML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/2007/12/11/2492.aspx)

Comment: Indeed, these are resources I've already been working with without any luck.

Comment: @Kezzer: So what's the question? You want to know the parameters needed for each w:val or...?

Comment: @Kezzer: Just wanted to follow up with you on this so we can see if we can get it resolved for you.

Answer (score 1):

Can this be of some help?

[Mail Merging With Word and Linq-to-Xml in VB](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121090048/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/12/06/mail-merging-with-word-and-linq-to-xml-in-vb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

in your sql command you aren't using regular single quotes (') but the kind i see when people have international keyboards ( "`" vs "'" ).  i don't know how the SQLOLEDB provider works but  i am used to seeing brackets around table and cloumn names rather than quotes.

using microsoft word, set up mail merging in a test document just how you want it.  then view the xml that word generated using the Open XML SDK *Tool* which you can get here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124

compare the xml that word generates to your code to see where you may have gone wrong.

note that a w:mailMerge may depend on an external resource, in which case you include a data source reference.